# Distance preservation measure for Random Projection evaluation

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, distance, multidimensional-scaling

Recently I have applied the Random Projection technique to several datasets. As you might know this method has the nice propoerty that pairwise distances between data points are approximatelly preserved: the Johnson–Lindenstrauss lemma states that:

$(1-\epsilon)||u-v||^2 \le ||f(u)-f(v)||^2 \le (1+\epsilon)||u-v||^2~~~~\forall u,v \in X$

Where $X$ is a set of $m$ points from $\mathbb{R}^d$, $0>\epsilon>1$ and depends on $m$ and $k$, and $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^k$ is the random projection.

However, the exact amount of distance distortion induced by random projection varies when one works with different datasets and even between random projection matrix's instantiations.

My question is the following: **is there any standard measure to determine how much pairwise distances are distorted after random projection?** If you suggest any metric, please cite some papers that adopted it.

I have come up with the following measure, which I think naturally emerges looking at the JL lemma:

$distortion = \sum_{u,v \in X} \frac{abs(||f(u)-f(v)||^2 - ||u-v||^2)}{||u-v||^2}$

Unfortunatelly I have been unable to find any reference that uses this or a similar measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compare to stress as defined here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling